# Short Javascript code snippet involving if / else not being evaluated correctly

Tags: javascript

For some reason, the evaluator `if isEven(n)` is giving an error... can you spot an issue with the code?

```
function isEven(value) {
    //value = Number(value);
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


function testCondition {

    if isEven(n) {

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: "is giving an error" --- we need to guess now?

Comment: Oh I see, no syntax error in `isEven`, just bad indenting. In any case, you can do this `function isEven(v){ return v%2 === 0 }`. Much simpler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **two** syntax errors in your code:

```
function isEven(value) {
    //value = Number(value);
if (value%2 == 0) // no parens here is allowed so no syntax error
    return true;
else
    return false;
}


function testCondition() {
                   // ^^ missing parens here

  if (isEven(n)) {
  // ^ ------- ^ -- and here

            } 
  else {

       }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if isEven(n) {
```

You're missing parenthesis around this, so you'll get a *SyntaxError*

```
if (isEven(n)) {
```

You're also missing a `()` after `testCondition`, [as pointed out by Frits van Campen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355399#17355434).

Comment: `testCondition` is also missing parens.

Comment: @MattGreer this is true

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor syntax issues, try this:

```
function isEven(value) {
    //value = Number(value);
    if (value%2 == 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}


function testCondition() {

    if (isEven(n)) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}
```